# How to encode package and function names in Android?

Tags: java, android, encode

I want to change all package and function names to make my app harder to analyze.
I reversed other apk and found what I want.
But I don't know how to do like this.
Please check attached image.[image]

Do I have to use any other tool or change this manually?
Please give me a hint.
Thanks!

Comment: Yep. You want [ProGuard](https://google.com?q=proguard%20obfuscation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `build.gradle` of app module, enable minify to shorten and obfuscate your codes.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        // your code will be shortened and obfuscated by R8 compiler
        // in the release build of your app.
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

See also : https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Is it possible with the built apk?

Comment: @Dream811 I don't think it's possible.